# Segmentation error when using cx_Oracle with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I am using cx_Oracle and pandas in my project. Whenever I run cx_Oracle individually, it Connects succesfully. But after importing pandas it fails with segmentation error.

Output of pip show

Name: cx-Oracle

Version: 7.2.2

Name: pandas

Version: 0.25.1

Code used to connect to oracle

```py
 #import pandas
 import cx_Oracle
 dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('hostname','port',sevice_name='service_name')
 conn = cx_Oracle.connect("username","password",dsn)
 print("Connection Successful!")
```

Above code prints

Connection Successful!

But when import pandas is uncommented and used it throws-

Segmentation Fault(core dump)

```py
 import pandas
 import cx_Oracle
 dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('hostname','port',sevice_name='service_name')
 conn = cx_Oracle.connect("username","password",dsn)
 print("Connection Successful!")
```

I am using python 3.6

Comment: Are you running both successful and unsuccessful cases from the same terminal window?  If not, then at a guess, you have multiple versions of Oracle client libraries installed and there is a clash.

Comment: I am running both successful and unsuccessful cases from same terminal window. It just fails whenever I use pandas with it. Using other libraries is not making this error happen. But if pandas and cx_Oracle are imported together then it throwing the segmentation fault. @ChristopherJones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the conflicting issue by using `oracle instant client v18.5.0.0.0` instead of using `oracle instant client v19.3.0.0.0`. May be `glibc 2.14` has some conflicting errors which is a dependency of latest instant client.

If someone facing same issue please refer to `instant client v18.5.0.0.0` which requires `glibc 2.12`.

Oracle instant client download page : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html